# How to serialize a block in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to implement a controlled restart inside a role in Ansible. I need a set of tasks to run sequentially on each node in turn. It seems that I can't use serial on a block. Is there another way to do this? Throttle still executes each task in the block one by one and serial can only be used on a play.

Here is my role:

```
- name: Task 1
  debug:
    msg: "hello1"

- name: An example block
  block:
    - name: Task 2
      debug:
        msg: "Decommission Node"
    - name: Task 3
      debug:
        msg: "Restart Node"
    - name: Task 4
      debug:
        msg: "Recommission Node"
  throttle: 1
  # serial: 1
```

Comment: `serial` is a play level attributes and is not valid in tasks/blocks. If you want to use it, create a separate play inside your playbook with the given tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this at role level, this is a functionality limited to playbooks.

Think about a role as being some code that runs on a specific host, so looping over hosts should be done only at playbook level.

There are some tricks you could use to do some kind of looping inside a role but I will not go into the details because it will break badly in too many cases.

Answer (score 0):

In ansible(version 2.9 and later) throttle argument set the limit for workers per task and not per role as far as I could understood from my experience and checking documentation here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle

Check also relevant Github issue from ansible contributors regarding throttling in ansible:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/64659